# Tableview Cells Dequeing Prematurely after change in tableview height constraint

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've designed the screen to remove some views as the user scrolls down. This will also trigger an increase in height of the tableview covering for the "removed" views.

The problem is, when i scroll up, cells deque and disappear on the top edge of the old tableview height. This creates this blank gap since it deques prematurely.

How do I fix it so that it deques using the NEW top edge of the tableview?

Comment: can you please share the screenshot what you are getting and code which you have written in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate

Comment: @Shubhambairagi I'm returning a fixed height of 120. Cell heights are okay. It's just that when I scroll things get messed up as it deques prematurely at the top because the tableview has a new and larger height. Im not quite sure how to "Reset" to follow the new tableview top edge. I already did try tableview.reload